# Visual Studio 2017 msbuild package sharepoint

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-2013, visual-studio-2017

I have a simple SharePoint 2013 solution which I can publish through Visual Studio - this will generate .wsp for me. However when I am trying to run build by the command:

```
msbuild /t:Package mySolution.sln
```

Build is ok but during packaging I receive an error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets(190,5): error : Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Modeling.Sdk.15.0, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

If I put this missing dll to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\SharePointTools then I receive another error about another missing dll... 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The same error here:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/28775/can-not-create-wsp-package-for-sharepoint-2013-pro.html. Visual Studio team has determined that this issue is related to the SharePoint/Modeling SDK. So we suggest you can follow up with SharePoint/Modeling SDK teams' forum.

Comment: I have the same issue and asked a question on their forums: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f2394040-10db-45a2-bf92-5524f79200ad/building-wsps-via-command-line-with-vs2017?forum=sharepointdevelopment (hopefully this was the right one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is MSBuild issue:
1.Open elevated command prompt

2.Navigate to your SDK tools

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64"

3. Sn -Vr "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Modeling.Sdk.15.0.dll"
4. gacutil /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Modeling.Sdk.15.0.dll"
5. For the following three dlls, please do same behavior from step 3 to 4

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.dll

Note if Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.dll not found in above path, check in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.dll

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Models.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Designers.Models.Features.dll

6. Now you can MSBuild your SharePoint 2016 solutions by VS command promp.

Check Link, that's for Sharepoint 2016, but same works for 2013 as well: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40195/cant-use-msbuild-to-package-sharepoint-2016-soluti.html